# How to configure DNS for website on one host other domain services on second host?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, hosts

I want to achieve the following:

mydomain.com/webmail, mydomain.com/forums, mail.mydomain.com, etc point to current host A

And I wish to point mydomain.com to a new website host:

www.mydomain.com, mydomain.com point to website on host B, but only those urls do so.

The email is easy, add a new MX record for mail.mydomain.com and A record for mail.mydomain.com pointing to the mail server IP.

However, I cannot simply add an A record for mydomain.com to point to host B as then sub-directories such as mydomain.com/forums will no longer be reachable at host A.

Is there a solution to this that requires no changes for the enduser?

Answer (score 2):

There are no DNS records to do this, it has to be done at the HTTP level. You have to configure the web server on host B to reverse-proxy requests for `/webmail` and `/forums` to host A.